# How to flip the clause 'on' the inner join of self join many to many

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity that relates to herself

```
@OrderBy("ordenacao ASC")
@JoinTable(name = "funcionarios_has_funcionarios", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FUNCIONARIOS_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FUNCIONARIOS_ID1"))
@ManyToMany(cascade = { PERSIST, MERGE })
public List<Funcionarios> getFuncionariosId1s() {
    return funcionariosId1s;
}
```

I have this sql to run

```
"SELECT  f.id,f.nome, COALESCE (SUM(flp.litros * flp.valor),0) as total, "
                + "(select COALESCE (SUM(v.valor),0) from Vales as v where v.funcionario = f and v.status = 'PENDENTE') as vales, "
                + "(select COALESCE (SUM(c.valor),0) from Convenio as c where c.funcionarios = f  and c.statusconveniado = 'PENDENTE') as convenios "
                + "FROM Fornecimentoleiteprodutor as flp "
                + "INNER JOIN flp.produtor as f "
                + "INNER JOIN f.funcionariosId1s as mp "
                + "where mp.id= 2"
                + "GROUP BY f",`
```

she performs in java that way

```
`select
        funcionari1_.ID as col_0_0_,
        funcionari1_.NOME as col_1_0_,
        coalesce(sum(fornecimen0_.LITROS*fornecimen0_.VALOR),
        0) as col_2_0_,
        (select
            coalesce(sum(vales4_.VALOR),
            0) 
        from
            vales vales4_,
            funcionarios funcionari5_ 
        where
            vales4_.FUNCIONARIOS_ID=funcionari5_.ID 
            and vales4_.FUNCIONARIOS_ID=funcionari1_.ID 
            and vales4_.STATUS='PENDENTE') as col_3_0_,
        (select
            coalesce(sum(convenio6_.VALOR),
            0) 
        from
            convenio convenio6_,
            funcionarios funcionari7_ 
        where
            convenio6_.FUNCIONARIOS_ID=funcionari7_.ID 
            and convenio6_.FUNCIONARIOS_ID=funcionari1_.ID 
            and convenio6_.STATUSCONVENIADO='PENDENTE') as col_4_0_ 
    from
        fornecimentoleiteprodutor fornecimen0_ 
    inner join
        funcionarios funcionari1_ 
            on fornecimen0_.PRODUTOR_ID=funcionari1_.ID 
    inner join
        funcionarios_has_funcionarios funcionari2_ 
            on funcionari1_.ID=funcionari2_.FUNCIONARIOS_ID 
    inner join
        funcionarios funcionari3_ 
            on funcionari2_.FUNCIONARIOS_ID1=funcionari3_.ID 
    where
        funcionari3_.ID=2 
    group by
        funcionari1_.ID`
```

but I need the clause 'on' the second 'inner join is different, this way

```
inner join
        funcionarios_has_funcionarios funcionari2_ 
            on funcionari1_.ID=funcionari2_.FUNCIONARIOS_ID1
```

i need that the 'on' relate the second column of the connection table
how do I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the inner join give your own ON clause.

At present Hibernate is generating its own ON clause based on its own assumptions.

Comment: Any JPA implementation will always add an ON clause based on what the annotations/XML define the columns as (and hence what should be joined). You cannot get rid of that (other than define your relation fields differently). The only thing you can do is ADD additional ON clause(s) using JPQL.

Comment: I just want to change the 'id' compared in 'on'